# Why does new.Date() differs 1 hour from new.Date().toISOString()?

Tags: javascript, datetime, methods

Please someone explain me this situation.

I have the following code:

```
<p>Click the button to display the date and time as a string, using the ISO standard.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toISOString();
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = d;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>
```

And I get the following result:

```
Click the button to display the date and time as a string, using the ISO standard.

Try it

Mon Apr 06 2015 19:07:55 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

2015-04-06T18:07:55.739Z
```

Why does the `toISOString()` method "take" 1 hour away from `new Date()`???

Comment: The answer is right under your eyes: `GMT+0100`

Comment: Are you asking why you live in a timezone that is one hour ahead of GMT, and why GMT time isn't the same as the time where you live ?

Comment: @blex I see that! But I also see hour=19.

Comment: @adeneo that's not what I'm asking. new Date() gives Mon Apr 06 2015 19:07:55 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time). Why when using toISOString method hour is 18 and not 19?

Comment: Well, where you live, it's 7pm (19), because your timezone is 1 hour ahead from the GMT time. So, the actual GMT time is 6pm (18). Does that make sense?

Comment: @blex of course that makes sense. I know that my timezone is 1 hour ahead from GMT. What I don´t understand is why when I use new Date() it shows GMT+0100 but also shows 19 as my timezone hour. Why when I use toISOString method it shows GMT time and not mine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trailing Z(*because of which you are facing the difference*) which represents Zulu timezone. Your actual time is perhaps 1 hour ahead of the GMT time. And if you want to get rid of the difference because of that you can try this:

```
var x = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; 
var localISOTime = (new Date(Date.now() - x)).toISOString().slice(0,-1);
```

**On a side note:**

`moment.js` is good option to choose to get rid of these issues.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Tripathi. For now I used your code and works fine. I'll take a look at "moment.js" but as I already am using many "js" files in my web site, I'm trying not to use more.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi Thanks bro I have used this code for TS and works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO
>   format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 characters long:
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ. **The timezone is always zero UTC offset**, as
>   denoted by the suffix "Z".

(Emphasis mine)

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: I already read that MDN article but I cannot find an answer to my question. If new Date() gives Mon Apr 06 2015 19:07:55 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) - emphasis on the hour 19, why when using toISOString method the hour is 18?

Comment: @Zidrep, Because your OS timezone is configured as UTC+1, `new Date()` would return **19**, but since `toISOString()` is always UTC0 it returns **18**.

Comment: @Zidrep:- You need to understand the fact that your location is 1 hour ahead of the GMT time due to which you are getting the difference in time. The toISOString() returns the string in simplified extended ISO format. If you want to check the time without difference then check my answer!

Comment: Thanks also to you @haim770, for your explanation.